# Adding Multiple Xcode (ios) Projects in a single Project

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have 4 different app that are up and running .

For example lets say I have :Project 1 , Project 2, Project 3 & project 4. 
All app are running individually. Project 2,3 & 4 are already in app store.

I have added project 2,3,4 into project 1  using `canOpenURL:URL`,they are working fine. But when I have submitted Project 1 for app store review , they have rejected the app store saying

> we found that your app requires users to install other apps in order
>   to access the Project 2, Project 3 and Project 4 feature. This is not
>   in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.

Now what i want is to add those 3 projects in my project 1 as app bundle so that user can use the app without installing  Project 2, Project 3 and Project 4. I am new in IOS development , so please help me with your valuable suggestions . 
As I mentioned earlier  Project 2,3 & 4 are already in app store,so its impossible for me to remake them .

Thanks In Advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add targets in your application or you can add the project source code in your project. At run time you can check if the application is already installed in the device you can redirect user to it, else you can use the functionality from your project.

You can not add compulsion on the user to download another application to use one, you can always provide options to user to download the application to use certain functionality.(Like we have for social networking sharing, we always check for application status before showing option to user).

Hope my answer help you.